# Does the length of a bar magnet matter in producing EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider the following diagram. There are 3 apparatuses to produce EMF. The coils are identical in cross section area, the number of winding, and length. The bar  magnets have the same cross section but with different length. All magnets are moved back and forth periodically (and with the same phase)  with the same speed. $V$ represents the induced EMF.

[image]

My question is does the length of the bar magnet matter in this case?

Comment: What would happen if all three magnets were inside their respective coils, each coil was rigged up to a 9v battery, and you flipped three switches to send current through all three coils?

Comment: @JohnDuffield: The longest magnet would move the slowest  because it has the highest mass. Now what?

Comment: @CuriousOne : if you flipped it round, you'd have to move the longest magnet the slowest to induce the same voltage. So I was thinking V3>V2>V1. See [this](http://archive.org/stream/cu31924031248127/cu31924031248127_djvu.txt) and search on "longer magnet". See this: _"if the magnet be imagined to have no length — the two poles merged into the same point — it can be seen that the resultant force at all points about the magnet must be zero, for the forces due to the poles must be equal and opposite at every place"_. But note that this is just a comment, not an answer. I might have it wrong!

Comment: @JohnDuffield: You can't flip it around because the case that you describe and the case that the problem asks for are not identical.